# Install spefic package from wily repo

Tags: software-installation

I have Ubuntu 14.04
I need this package 
http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/rebar
How do I install it?

Comment: Just download and try to install. But probably dependencies will not let you. Maybe they will.

Comment: how I do it?I think I have the right dependencies as I installed erlang package

Comment: The version may be too old. Download deb and install.

Comment: The wily repo is a newer than trusty.What is the url to download the deb?

Comment: You gave the link to the `packages.ubuntu.com`. The link is there. Click your architecture and you will get links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a deb file for [64-bit](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rebar/rebar_2.6.0-1_amd64.deb) or [32-bit](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rebar/rebar_2.6.0-1_i386.deb) Ubuntu.

I tested it. It installs on Ubuntu 14.04.3.

Download it to your Home folder and run

```
sudo dpkg -i rebar*.deb
```

If some dependencies are not installed, run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: It install the right version?From the right repo?Because in the trusty there are version too and it is old one

Comment: This is the package from wily repository. In trusty it is `2.0.0-5`.

Answer (score 1):

first you have to install `erlang` using following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install erlang
```

this will install erlang and its dependencies then do

```
git clone git://github.com/rebar/rebar.git
cd rebar
./bootstrap
```

finally you will get like

[image: this]

check Version using command

```
sudo ./rebar -V
rebar 2.6.0 R16B03 20150915_025354 git 2.6.0-28-g894858d
```

i have tested this on Ubuntu 14.04